# How to show content when hovered over an image in CSS?

Tags: html, css

https://practice-project-html-css.vercel.app/#project

I'm talking about "PROJECTS".

When you hover there, it shows some text. How do I make it?

Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAlSQ.jpg

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-container">
        <div class="one"><img src="project1.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="two"><img src="Project2.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="three"><img src="project3.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="four"><img src="project4.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="five"><img src="project5.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="six"><img src="project6.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="seven"><img src="project7.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="eight"><img src="project8.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="nine"><img src="project9.png" alt="" /></div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap:40px;
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this effect, you can use a combination of the `overflow` and `position` properties. The idea is to set `overflow-y: hidden;` and give it a set height. Then, position the child container so that it falls outside of the parent container. When the parent container is hovered, the `bottom` property along with `position: absolute;` can be used to `transition` it into view.

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  background-color: #888;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.image-container:hover .container-text {
  bottom: 0px;
}

.container-text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -60px;
  left: 0;
  transition: bottom 200ms;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #444;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  Hover me
  <div class="container-text">Message</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this example.

`https://codepen.io/francisco-kataldo/pen/LBBryV`

If you want more you can check this page.

```
https://ordinarycoders.com/blog/article/codepen-bootstrap-card-hovers
```

Comment: I'm using only css atm.

Comment: This example is not using javascript. Only bootstrap